# Find random Facebook user picture via Graph API

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [objective c facebook graph return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758090/objective-c-facebook-graph-return-false)

I am building an app that returns a random Facebook profile picture. So far I have the code below generating a random profile ID which sometimes does return a real profile but sometimes doesn't and just shows the generic blue Facebook face. When I use the given number on the actual website graph API it just returns false. My question is how would I put the code in so that if the random number generated returns a false profile, it just keeps generating a new random number until a real profile is returned, thus a real picture?

```
@implementation FacebookPicturesViewController

- (IBAction) nextImagePush {

    NSString *prefix = @"http://graph.facebook.com/";
    NSString *profileId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%09d", abs(arc4random())];
    NSLog(@"profileId: %@", profileId);
    NSString *suffix = @"/picture?type=large";
    NSString* url= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", prefix, profileId, suffix];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
    [imageView setImage:img];
    imageCount++;

    NSLog(@"profileId: %@", profileId);

    if (imageCount >= [imageArray count]){
        imageCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the original question instead of posting a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

'false' usually indicates a privacy check failed.
Check that the user hasn't blocked you or the app, and check they haven't disabled Platform entirely, deactivated their account, etc.